# Motor skill: Let speed come naturally?

Tags: technique, training, coaching

I've commonly heard that when practising a motor skill, one should start slow with correct form and one shouldn't force speed. Rather, let speed come naturally. I believe this but I can't find a citation for its prescription. Does anyone have a study to support (or deny) this?

Comment: Although your question of motor skills is related to Sports SE, https://gaming.stackexchange.com may be more relevant to the particularity of your question

Comment: Arqade (Gaming SE) was my favourite SE and where I have the most rep. But I doubt they'd answer a question like this. They barely have tags for something like this (mouse?). I feel you're only saying that just because I added that I'm particularly interested in its application to eSports and makes me regret adding that to my question. They're Gaming SE, not eSports SE. But if you insist.

Comment: @NiteCyper We don't insist, we're just trying to help you find where this question might fit best. You probably have more experience than most posters here on Arqade, so it sounds like it wouldn't fit there; I'm OK with leaving this open at least for now, but there is always a possibility that this question doesn't fit on any Stack Exchange site - SE doesn't aim to cater for every possible question out there. It is definitely worth noting that [e-sports are explicitly off-topic here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/are-e-sports-on-topic-here).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about sports.  As Philip notes, esports are not on topic here.

Comment: @Joe So if I remove the esports context, it should qualify again? That seems deeply unjust to me. Arqade is not E-sports Stack Exchange (SE). Probably the same way you feel Sports SE is not include E-sports SE. The core question applies to sports as fundamentally dependent on and defined by motor skill. And it's foolish of you to deny that and the value this question holds for your community. Arguably the only difference between sports and E-sports is proportion of fine vs gross motor skill. Especially in FPS games, fighting games, RTS games, or any other with high APM/execution requirements.

Comment: If you disagree with a long-standing policy on Sports SE, the appropriate process is to ask a question on Sports Meta. As Joe and Philip pointed out, e-sports are not sports for our purposes (and neither are chess, nor "running" or "skiing" for that matter). Removing the point that focuses on e-sports does mean it can be reopened however.

Comment: I don't think the question can be reopened, as it's still not *related to sports*.  Some questions just aren't good fits for any community, and that's okay.  This is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following citations don't speak to starting slow, but they confirm that speed and accuracy increase with practise.

> It is interesting that with practice, [...] limb trajectories get faster and more asymmetric (Elliott, Chua, Pollock, & Lyons, 1995; Khan & Franks, 2000).

[Elliott, D., Hansen, S., Grierson, L.E.M., Lyons, J., Bennett, S.J., Hayes, S.J. 2010. Goal-directed aiming: two components but multiple processes. *Psychological Bulletin*, 136, 1023-1044.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f0cb/b028b6248ac5fd74bbb22e2b65c13fbb6198.pdf) PDF page 5.

> Decrease in endpoint variability occurs in conjunction with an increase in the peak velocity of the limb (e.g., Elliott et al., 1995).

(Elliott et al., 2010, PDF page 10)

Edit: Found some more relevant sources.

> The group exposed to the slowest speed training program was the only group [...] which had significantly lower time-on-target scores from the control group who trained at the criterion speed.

[Barbara E. Jensen (1975) Pretask Speed Training and Movement Complexity as Factors in Rotary Pursuit Skill Acquisition, *Research Quarterly*. American Alliance for Health, Physical Education and Recreation, 46:1, 1-11](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10671315.1975.10615298), DOI: [10.1080/10671315.1975.10615298](https://doi.org/10.1080/10671315.1975.10615298)

> The effect of learning a novel skill at specific speeds on performance over a range of speeds was examined on [the pursuit rotor](https://www.google.com/search?q=pursuit+rotor). Three groups of subjects were given three days of training: Group 1 at 30 rpm, Group 2 at 60 rpm, and Group 3 at 30–45.60 rpm. Group 4, a control, practiced on a pegboard task during this period. On Days 4 and 5, all four groups were tested for transfer at 30, 45, and 60 rpm. For the most part, Group 3 appeared to perform equal to or better across the range of speeds than any of the other groups.

[Siegel, D., & Davis, C. (1980). Transfer Effects of Learning at Specific Speeds on Performance over a Range of Speeds. *Perceptual and Motor Skills*, 50(1), 83–89](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pms.1980.50.1.83). https://doi.org/10.2466/pms.1980.50.1.83

> Speed and accuracy are two sides of the same skill coin. although there is a strong and widespread belief in industry that the instructor should focus on developing accuracy because speed will follow, that is not true. The research is clear: if you want speed and accuracy, you must train for both and preferably right from the start of training.

[James, R. (1995). Chapter 8. In *The techniques of instruction* (p. 55). Aldershot, Hampshire, England: Gower.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=BqkpO46H5GsC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=The+result+of+speed+and+accuracy+emphases+on+the+learning+of+a+selected+motor+skill+in+golf&ots=tze717VyUs&sig=ACfU3U3wMdC7BhpiZBXxhHZhx4s4TcZTgQ&hl=en#v=onepage&q=The%20result%20of%20speed%20and%20accuracy%20emphases%20on%20the%20learning%20of%20a%20selected%20motor%20skill%20in%20golf&f=false)